# Использование одного объекта struct на несколько cpp файлов

Tags: c++, структуры-данных

Есть такая структура, объявленная в хидере main.h:

```
struct dbHead   //Заголов базы
{
    uint8_t tabVer;
    char dbName[DBNAME_length];
    uint16_t records;
    uint16_t bans;
};
```

Я попробовал использовать `extern` объявление `extern dbHead dbH` в хидере и `dbHead dbH` в cpp файле main.cpp. В случае с одним файлом всё работает и вопросов не возникает. Однако при написании такого же объявления в другом cpp файле - db.cpp - возникает ошибка линковщика

main.cpp

```
#include "main.h"
dbHead dbH;
```

db.cpp

```
#include "main.h"
dbHead dbH; //В этом файле если так написать то будет ошибка линковки
```

Попытка обратиться к полям структуры из другого cpp "в лоб" вызывают ошибки о невозможности найти такой объект(ожидаемо, ведь его не объявили)

Естественно во всех случаях был прописан `#include "main.h"`

Можно ли как-то объявить один общий объект структуры на несколько cpp файлов, так как подразумевается что файлы будут обмениваться данными этого объекта между собой

Comment: У всех получается, а у Вас нет. В main.h напишите extern dbHead dbH, в main.cpp - #include "main.h"
dbHead dbH;, в остальных - #include "main.h".

Comment: Я так делал уже. У меня в итоге такой лог:

Comment: error C3927: "->": использование завершающего возвращаемого типа не допускается после декларатора, который не является функцией
error C3484: синтаксическая ошибка: требуется "->" перед возвращающим типом
error C3613: отсутствует тип возвращаемого значения после "->" (предполагается int)
error C4430: отсутствует спецификатор типа - предполагается int. Примечание. C++ не поддерживает int по умолчанию

Comment: error C2371: dbH: переопределение; различные базовые типы
note:  см. объявление "dbH"
error C2146: синтаксическая ошибка: отсутствие ";" перед идентификатором "bans"

Что я не так делаю?

Я написал вот такое выражение dbH.bans = 0;

Comment: 1. stdint.h включили? 2. К членам структуры обращаетесь через точку, а не через ->?

Comment: Конечно, как и main.h. Я обращаюсь через точку(логично же) У меня первый раз такое. Я до этого на си(с gcc) сидел и не было такого. Может в VS2017 что-то нужно в настройках поменять?

Comment: Что-то с компилятором не так, может INCLUDE не прописаны? Какую первую ошибку он выдаёт? Кстати, в C++ можно написать inline dbHead dbH; в хидере и в main.cpp его не определять, но сишный подход тоже должен работать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Короче, смысл вот в чём: объявление `extern` в ***хэдере*** говорит компилятору о том, что данная переменная находятся где-то в другом объектном модуле или библиотеке. А объявление без `extern` в ***cpp-файле*** определяет переменную в данном конкретном объектном модуле, в который компилируется данный конкретный cpp-файл. Соответственно, если объявить эту переменную ***дважды***, как у вас, в двух разных cpp-файлах, а затем после компиляции скормить их линкеру, то возникнет конфликт - линкер просто не будет знать, какую версию из этих двух переменных выбрать. Переменая должна быть объявлена один раз, в каком-то одном из cpp-файлов - тогда связывание пройдёт успешно.

main.h

```
struct dbHead   //Заголов базы
{
    uint8_t tabVer;
    char dbName[DBNAME_length];
    uint16_t records;
    uint16_t bans;
};

extern dbHead dbH; //объявляем переменную, как внешнюю
```

main.cpp

```
#include "main.h"
dbHead dbH; //переменная будет найдена линкером в модуле main.o
```

db.cpp

```
#include "main.h"
//dbHead dbH; - нет, не надо тут ещё раз её объявлять! Она уже объявлена в main.cpp!
```

А  по поводу остальных ошибок - похоже, что где-то вы напортачили в тексте, нужно больше исходника, чтобы понять в чём дело. Вы пишите, что написали `dbH.bans = 0;` - где вы это написали? В файле db.cpp? Внутри какой-то функции? Или просто сразу после `#include "main.h"`? Если вне тела функции, то для внешних переменных это не работает. Если нет, то опять же - нужны более полные ваши исходники.